# Js on scroll event scroll to next/previous div

Tags: javascript, html, scrollto, onscroll

I'm trying to make a website scroll divs. When a visiter wants to scroll it should automatically go to the next or previous div.

Below you can see how my html looks like.

```
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentv1">
        </div>
        <div id="contentv2">
        </div>
        <div id="contentv2">
        </div>
        <div id="contentv2">
        </div>
        <div id="contentv3">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying it with the following code:

```
(function() {
var scrollTo = function(element) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: element.offset().top
    }, 500);
}
$('body').mousewheel(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $current = $('#content > .current');
    if ($current.index() != $('#content > div').length - 1) {
        $current.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
        scrollTo($current.next());
    }
});
$('body').mousewheel(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $current = $('#content > .current');
    if (!$current.index() == 0) {
        $current.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
        scrollTo($current.prev());
    }
});
})();
```

The header has an height of 10% and sticks to the top. The content divs have a height of 90%. So when scrolled the top of the content divs should aline with the bottom of the header.

Can anyone help me into the right direction?

Comment: You have loaded a plugin that provides the mousewheel event watcher, right?

Comment: No I've not, where can I find it? And is the script correct besides the plugin you mentioned?

Comment: You can find one here: http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/. Otherwise, `!$current.index == 0` is sort of strange, I'd probably use `$current.index !== 0`.

Comment: I've added jquery.mousewheel.min.js to the head and changed $current.index !==0, but I',m not getting it to work... I've created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LennartB/cztL7h49/ If anyone can help me, please!